# need help with ( Tor onion ) theres this error that pops up at sites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, error

this is very strange whenever i go to any web site while using tor it wont let me theres this weird looking monster looking picture which is named monster onion

and it says with the fellowing 'This is rotten onion.'

Under United States jurisdiction we are unable to relay to:...

it always shows me that and no one has any idea what im talking about when i ask for help

i seem to remember ones that allowing scripts globally (dangerous) seemed to fix this problem but not any more for whatever reason any help please
See full content

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like shenanigans, but on whose end I'm not sure.

1. Find another computer, like in a public library.
2. Download Tor Browser Bundle again (from here: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)
3. Open it and go to a reliable hidden service (Ahmia Tor Hidden Service Search: http://msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion/search/)

If this solves the issue, try running a virus and malware scan on your computer, deleting your Tor Browser Bundle, and re-downloading it again.  Avoid using addons other than the ones installed, and keep NoScript on if at all possible.

If this did not solve the issue, then you may be getting redirected/intercepted.  Try using a bridge to connect to Tor (see: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en).  If you still have issues, you might need to look at using a pluggable transport (also discussed at previous link).

Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting errors with that "Ahmia Tor Hidden Service Search" URI from the Tor Browser

Comment: @WGroleau Does it not load at all, or does it give a special error? The service has been less stable lately for some reason.

Comment: "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion"

Comment: Looks like the server may be offline. It's been intermittent for me, too. Try to find the URL for The Hidden Wiki (the Tor version, should end in .onion) and connect to that. Their service is fairly reliable. I'd get the URL myself, but I'm away from a computer at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attemption in the URL that you are trying to access.

If the end has a ".city" (i.e.: afksldhfkhkejhks.onion.city/main_page/)in the URL's end, just delete the ".city" and retry.

Onion City is a mechanism to turn .onion sites accessible trough the clearnet via an unconfigured browser.

But the service is hosted in the (opressive) USA, so, they will deny access to anything that they finds "illegal".